# Custom Checkbox background Image not coming - Bootstrap 4 after Angular 5 Deployment

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I tried make custom checkbox using bootstrap 4 in angular 5.
All are working fine. But Background image(tick) not showing.

```
<label class="form-check-label custom-checkbox">
    <input class="form-check-input custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span> Some Text Here </span>
</label>
```

Comment: have you inspected that image into DOM? can you reproduce same error in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xntlyv?

Comment: ya its showing in inspect.

Comment: .custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-indicator {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' v…M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E);
}

Comment: Maybe it's related to your site's Content Security Policy. I had a problem similar problem related to this issue in Bootstrap 4 - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25394